# How exactly do Amazon MWS Order Reports work

Tags: amazon-mws

I used MWS scratchpad to schedule Order Reports with the _15_MINUTES_ schedule, I thought that every 15 minutes, a new order report will be created and I can download it, however, only 1 report has been created (I changed the IDS for public display)

```
<ReportInfo>
  <ReportType>_GET_ORDERS_DATA_</ReportType>
  <Acknowledged>false</Acknowledged>
  <ReportId>2456744422183913</ReportId>
  <ReportRequestId>12543213592</ReportRequestId>
  <AvailableDate>2019-10-04T09:20:24+00:00</AvailableDate>
</ReportInfo>
```

So how do I get new orders, is it that every 15 minutes, the same report will be updated with the new orders? will I never ever have to schedule order reports after this? I'm not clear on how it works. 
I'm using the python3 mws API for my work if it helps.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this: [What you should know about the Amazon MWS Reports API section](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_Overview.html), if you haven't already.

A new report will be generated at the time interval you specified.  It will be a completely new report with a different id.  You can query `GetReportRequestList` for the status and then when the report is ready, call `GetReport` with the ReportID from the previous step.

Your schedule should be indefinite.  Check to make sure your report is schedulable and see if there are restrictions on how often you can request it.